R quanteda: search using multilevel dictionary
I need to perform a search on a set of documents by dictionary pairs topic.keyword / keyword.topic, in any order.
If either topic or keyword are not found, "NA" to be returned.
Only in case if BOTH topic and keyword are found, topic.keyword combination to be returned.
My current R-code is:

txt <- c(d1 = "smth topic1 smth keyword1 keyword2 smth smth keyword3 smth",
d2 = "smth keyword3 smth smth",
d3 = "smth keyword3 smth topic2 smth smth")

toks_txt <- tokens(txt)

df_dict <- data.frame(topic = c("topic1", "topic1", "topic2", "topic2"), 
                          keywords = c("keyword1    keyword2", "keyword3", "keyword4 keyword5", "keyword3"))

dict <- dictionary(list(`topic1` = list(`keyword1`= "keyword1",
                                            `keyword2` = "keyword2"),
                            `topic2` = list(`keyword3` = "keyword3",
                                            `keyword1` = "keyword1")))

lookup <- tokens_lookup(toks_txt, dict, levels = 1:2, nomatch = "NA")

Actual outcome - tokens consisting of 2 documents:
d1 :
[1] "NA" "NA" "NA" "topic1.keyword1 keyword2" "NA" "NA" "topic1.keyword3" "topic2.keyword3" "NA"

d2 :
[1] "NA" "topic1.keyword3" "topic2.keyword3" "NA" "NA"

d3 :
[1] "NA" "topic1.keyword3" "topic2.keyword3" "NA" "NA" "NA" "NA"

Desired outcome - tokens consisting of 2 documents:
d1 :
[1] "NA" "NA" "NA" "topic1.keyword1 keyword2" "NA" "NA" "topic1.keyword3" "NA" "NA"

d2 :
[1] "NA" "NA" "NA" "NA"

d3 :
[1] "NA" "topic2.keyword3" "NA" "NA" "NA" "NA"

Any advice and help would be highly appreciated.

Could you clarify exactly what you mean by "Only in case if BOTH topic and keyword are found, topic.keyword combination to be returned."? Also, the "actual outcome" above is not the actual outcome for this code. What about using reprex::reprex()?

Hi Ken,
Thanks for correcting the output format, I will use the package further on.

"Only in case if BOTH topic and keyword are found, topic.keyword combination to be returned." means e.g. in the above example, d2 has the value "keyword3" from the "keyword" list, but has no value from the "topic" list, so I expect NA to return. However, the current code returns "topic1.keyword3".

That's still not the actual output. which for d1 includes the sequence "topic1.keyword1" "topic2.keyword1" "topic1.keyword2", for instance. Anyway, is your desired output not a logical for each document indicating the presence or absence of the condition that it contains a reference to both any topic aand any keyword? I'm still not clear.

Hi Ken,

When I run the code in R-studio, it is an actual output.
If a document has keyword but doesn't have a topic, I'd like NA to return, but currently I get topic.keyword.
Hope this brings more clarity.


You should use reprex::reprex() because that is not the actual output. What does df_dict do here?

df_dict shows how the original dataframe for dictionary looks like. I didn't show the R-code to get dict from df-dict as it's not relevant to the issue. If dict should look differently to solve the problem, please provide an example. Thank you.
